# Is there any way to preseve type in angular templates when using as keyword?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-aot

Angular can typecheck your templates in [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#phase-3-binding-expression-validation) and throw errors at compilation phase.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when using `as` keyword, for example in `ngIf`:

`*ngIf="typedVariable as newVariable"` or in more common case, `*ngIf="typedObservable | async as newVariable"`.

`newVariable` in both cases is not type safe, i.e. I can do `{{ newVariable.anyInvalidPropertyNameNotPresentInTypedVariable }}` without any errors or warnings (which is not the case with `{{ typedVariable.anyInvalidPropertyNameNotPresentInTypedVariable }}`).

Is there any way to achieve type safety, especially in `async as` case?

Comment: In your example, `newVariable` is just an alias of `typedVariable` and corresponds to the typed object emitted from the Observable. So the same behavior should be exposed whether you use `as` syntax or not. 

[**Because you are using `ngIf`**](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#type-narrowing) Typescript compiler infers that `typedVariable` will never be undefined.

Comment: Thank you @Und3rTow, can you confirm that in actual code? Because I've tried that, also with Ivy compiler, and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Also, to clarity @Und3rTow, you are right, Typescript compiler infners that `typedVariable` will never be undefined, but because of `as` it will lose `typedVariable` type, i.e. `newVariable` will be treated "as  `any`".

Comment: I don't think it looses it's type. It's just that you can't implicitly "type check" it anymore because the `ngIf` directive acts as a guard so the erroneous property will not be displayed.

Comment: Here is a fairly in-depth article on this - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/

Comment: Just to clarify one more thing, `typeVariable` is complex object and I don't want to validate if it is 'undefined' or not. `ngIf` works as a guard, that's great, I know it will not be undefined, but I also want to know, that if `typedVariable` is described by interface, for example `{ prop: string }` then I'll be warned about using it improperly, i.e. `{{ newVariable.porp }}` instead of `{{ newVariable.prop }}'.

Comment: Yes I understand, and it is a perfectly reasonable expectation. To do it in that way, I guess you would need to drop the use of `ngIf` as well as the `async` pipe so that `fullTemplateTypeCheck` can validate the bindings at compile time. For what it's worth, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24598) for this specifically.